# Optimizing bitwise filtering in SQL

Tags: sql, optimization, bitwise-operators

I am implementing a bitwise filter using SQL, and I want to see if the following optimization is **always valid in all cases**, and I'm not sure how to prove it.
My goal is to limit the number of rows that get compared.

Standard filter pseudo-sql:

```
IF (A & B = A) // SHOW VALUE
```

The question is, will it work to add this? :

```
IF (A = B) OR (A & B = A) WHERE (B >= A) // SHOW VALUE
```

It seems to me that B must always be >= to A - is there a case where this is not true?

I realize that the above code is still not optimal, I just want to know if this is a viable direction to go in.

Does someone have some amazing maths to help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you are dealing with unsigned ints (whether as a column type in mysql, or as a contraint in other dbs), then this is true:

```
(A & B == A) implies (B >= A) *not* (A >= B)
```

The math of it is that B must have all of the bits in A set, and possibly more. If a single bit from A was not set in B, then A & B != A.

(Note that the converse is not always true: (B >= A) does not imply that (A & B == A). As a simple counterexample, 5 > 3, but 3 & 5 = 1.)

Also, as soon as you get into negative numbers, you may run into situations where A & B = A, but B < A.

One more thing: (A & B = A) includes the case where (A = B), so saying

```
IF (A = B) OR (A & B = A) ...
```

is redundant. Remove the (A = B) unless you can see a speed difference with your SQL engine.

Comment: Thanks for the dyslexia check - I edited the question to reflect the good maths.